# Best language for large number of string comparisons

Tags: twitter, performance

I am starting a website which will grab a lot of data from the Twitter API.  I then want to look for certain phrases in the tweets that I get from the API.  I'm wondering what the best language would be for this.  Most of my knowledge is in PHP, but from what I've read in the past I am leaning more towards python.  Like I said before I will be looking for certain phrases so I would like to use something similar to PHP's strpos function.  I am looking for a language that will have fastest processing time.  I will also be doing a lot of INSERTs with this code but I figure that the string processing is going to take up most of the time, so I am focusing on that.  Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of my projects harvests tweets from many developers, and then filters that corpus down to only those tweets relevant to technology and development.  The cost of fetching those tweets from Twitter *dwarfs* the time taken to search the strings.

I say that you should pick a language that you enjoy (my weapon of choice is C#) and ensure that you are using an efficient and appropriate algorithm to perform your search -- SEK posted a very good link to get you started.

Of additional importance is having a good strategy for processing the tweets, and this is where you can be killed by Twitter's performance.  What works well for me is to have a process (or processes on multiple machines) that uses a multi-threaded, asynchronous client to fetch the tweets and place them into a datastore for processing. It is solely the  responsibility for this process to fetch the tweets from Twitter as fast as possible. Another multi-threaded service process is responsible for checking the fetched tweets for matches to my target phrases.

Answer (score 3):

If your set of search terms is fixed, [the esmre library for Python](http://code.google.com/p/esmre/) could be just what you need. It uses Aho-Corasick to do fast substring matching against large sets of search terms.

Here's an example that uses esmre to find mentions of some programming languages:

```
import esm

tweets = """
I've always loved Python.
C# is better than I thought. It's like Java done right.
My tiny mind cannot grasp Haskell.
Objective-C is like C and Smalltalk's illegitimate lovechild.
""".strip().split('\n')

search_terms = ["Python", "Ruby", "PHP", "Erlang", "Haskell", "OCaml",
    "Objective-C", "C#", "C++", "Common Lisp", "Scheme", "Java", "Smalltalk",
    " C "
]

# Build the index of search terms
index = esm.Index()

for term in search_terms:
    index.enter("%s" % term.lower(), term)

index.fix()

# Find mentions of the search terms
for tweet in tweets:
    matches = index.query(tweet.lower())
    languages = [label for (position, label) in matches]

    print "%r mentions %r" % (tweet, languages)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your thought that the string comparison will take the most time is correct, however the performance will likely be the same for whichever language you choose to use. So your best option is to pick the one you are most comfortable with. On the other hand, learning a new language can only increase your knowledge, and python's syntax will make you a better programmer.

In any case, it's far more important that you use appropriate algorithms for string searching and indexing. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_search) has a decent article that should give you an overview of the various algorithms. From your description, it sounds as if you'd be best off using a finite pattern set search, with a preference for ones that preprocess the patterns, such as Aho-Corasick.